# Beam momentum positive/negative sign

Tags: momentum, structural-beam

Could anyone explain to me why the momentum of this isostatic beam in $A$ is negative instead of positive?

Why isn't it as simple as $+FL-FL/2 = +FL/2$?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is what is required for the beam to be *static*.

For the beam to be static, at any point you need $\sum M = 0$; which your setup does not give.  If you start by assuming that $\sum  M = 0$ at any point on the beam, you should be able to solve for the moment at A and see why it is $\frac {FL}2$.

If the sum of moments is not zero, that would mean the beam is rotating.

Comment: Wait, so if I understand you correctly, the beam in the picture is not static? In the picture, $\frac {FL}2$ is negative because of the direction of the rotation, but it would actually have to be rotating the other way to be positive and make the beam static, right?

Comment: @Narcis No, this beam is static.  Choose point A, B or C to sum your moments up, leave the moment at A as a variable, and solve for it.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, until now I just did not understand how positive versus how negative moments are drawn/represented, but reading through your comments helped me clear up my misconceptions, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, it’s not “momentum”, it’s “moment”.

Secondly, for static equilibrium the algebraic sum of forces have to be zero and the sum of the moments about any point on the beam has zero.

The sign (+ or -) of the moment is purely arbitrary as long as you are consistent. The upper right corner of your diagram indicates counter clockwise moments are positive and clockwise moments are negative.

The beam depicted appears to be a cantilever. Since the sum of all the applied forces is zero, there is no vertical or horizontal reaction at A. We only have a moment reaction at A.

Taking the sum of the moments about A using the sign convention given

$$M_{A}+\frac{FL}{2}-FL=0$$

$$M_{A}=-\frac{FL}{2}$$

And the moment about A is negative.

But if we use the reverse for our sign convention we have

$$M_{A}-\frac{FL}{2}+FL=0$$

$$M_{A}=+\frac{FL}{2}$$

And the moment about A is positive.

So if the term on the right side of your equation is intended to be $M_{A}$, that would be OK but you would need to reverse the sign convention in the upper right corner of the diagram to be consistent.

Hope this helps